# Not able to select option in Bootstrap Drop Down Menu in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap drop down menu and populating it dynamically using DOM.

**HTML code**..

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-button">
            <label for="category">Category</label><br />
            <button id="dropdownbuttoncategory" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" required> Category <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul id="dropdownmenucategory" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <!--li being populated dynamically--> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
       //populate li's dynamically
        function loadCategoryDropdownContinued(obj){
        var ul = document.getElementById("dropdownmenucategory");

        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.id = catName;
        li.className = "category";

        li.innerHTML = obj.catName;

        var lidivider = document.createElement("li");
        lidivider.className = "divider";

        ul.appendChild(lidivider);
        ul.appendChild(li);

        getNextCategory(catName);
    }

    //code to get selected li 
    $(document).on("click",".category",function(event){         //to see which option is selected from dropdown category
        var text = document.getElementById(event.target.id).innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("dropdownbuttoncategory").innerHTML = text;             

    });
```

I tested this code and it works fine everywhere except Safari in iOS. There the drop down list gets dynamically populated but not able to select any option. Can't understand where I'm going wrong.Please help...